# TinyMCE is stripping out my <button> statement

Tags: php, html, tinymce-4

I've written a PHP application that uses TinyMCE 4.2.6 as a content manager. However, I've discovered in creating some Twitter Bootstrap HTML code that my button statements are getting stripped.

I've tried adding it to the extended_valid_elements in the tinyMCE.init statement like this:

```
extended_valid_elements : "button[class|style|id]"
```

but it's still going away. Per comments on the question, here's my entire init block now. I'm still not getting my HTML button to stick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    selector    : "textarea.tinymceEditor",
    plugins     : [ "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview textcolor anchor",
                    "searchreplace visualblocks code hr fullscreen table contextmenu paste"
                  ],
    toolbar     : "bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
    menubar     : "edit view format table",
    menu        : {
                    edit    : {title : "Edit"  , items : "undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | searchreplace | selectall"},
                    view    : {title : "View"  , items : "visualblocks visualaid | preview fullscreen | code"},
                    format  : {title : "Format", items : "bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat | hr "},
                    table   : {title : "Table" , items : "inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column"},
                  },
    forced_root_block : false,
    valid_elements : "*[*]"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366883/tinymce-stripping-html

Comment: I had previously read that article. However, just adding button to the extended_valid_elements isn't doing it...

Comment: What about the accepted answer?  Have you tried globally allowing everything just to see if the config you're playing with is affecting behavior?

Comment: Since adding "button" to extended_valid_elements isn't working for me, I was looking to find the appropriate adjustment to the the init that will enable it. Globally enabling everything is an acceptable answer. How do I do that?

Comment: So I found an article that said all I had to do was add `valid_elements:"[*]"` and I'm golden. Except that didn't work either. So here's my entire init block:

Comment: And I've just also tried `valid_elements : "+*[*]"` without success either. Not having a good day.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that part of my issue has been how my button statement was formulated. If there was a paragraph embedded within the button, the button got lost. If I change the paragraph to a span, it seems to work better. Strange but I can deal with that...